# Query strings in htaccess based on cookie

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have an htaccess problem that I can't manage to solve, I fact, I've spent like 5 hours now without success.

1. If the cookies 1, 2 or 3 exist
2. Then it should add a query string "value=true" to any URL, unless its an resource like css or js, as can be seen in the code below, on that site as long as that cookie still exists
3. And if a query string already exists, could be whatever, such as
   example.com/?test=test&value=true
   It should be added last in the query string chain and with a "&" to make it a valid query string

Here is the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# If Query String already exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (1|2|3)(.*)=(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(value=true)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} https://www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?value=true [QSA,R]
</IfModule>
```

The redirect doesn't append the query string to sitewide internal links if the cookie exists, in the code specified above.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not really clear, what you are asking or what the problem is. "Didn't work either.." isn't a specific problem description.

Comment: You are totally correct! I was in a hurry when posting this. However, the redirect doesn't append the query string to sitewide internal links if the cookie exists, in the code specified above.